# array_map with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace, array-map

Is it possible to use `array_map` in conjunction with `str_replace` without calling another function to do the `str_replace`?

For example:
`array_map(str_replace(' ', '-', XXXXX), $myArr);`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Map `str_replace()` to an array, or map the result of replacing something as a function name, to the array?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? :)

Comment: each element of the array to have str_replace

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is no need for array_map. From the [docs](http://php.net/str_replace): "If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed with every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well."

Answer (score 14):

No, it's not possible. Though, if you are using PHP 5.3, you can do something like this:

```
$data = array('foo bar baz');
$data = array_map(function($value) { return str_replace('bar', 'xxx', $value); }, $data);
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo xxx baz
)
```

Comment: @mkilmanas, what did you mean? And what was the reason for downvoting (if it was you)?

Answer (score 9):

Sure it's possible, you just have to give `array_map()` the correct input for the callback function.

```
array_map(
    'str_replace',            // callback function (str_replace)
    array_fill(0, $num, ' '), // first argument    ($search)
    array_fill(0, $num, '-'), // second argument   ($replace)
    $myArr                    // third argument    ($subject)
);
```

But for the particular example in the question, as [chiborg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226594/array-map-with-str-replace/6226711#6226711) said, there is no need. `str_replace()` will happily work on an array of strings.

```
str_replace(' ', '-', $myArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be important to note that if the array being used in `str_replace` is multi-dimensional, `str_replace` won't work.

Though this doesn't directly answer the question of using `array_map` w/out calling an extra function, this function may still be useful in place of `str_replace` in `array_map`'s first parameter if deciding that you need to use `array_map` and string replacement on multi-dimensional arrays. It behaves the same as using `str_replace`:

```
function md_str_replace($find, $replace, $array) {
/* Same result as using str_replace on an array, but does so recursively for multi-dimensional arrays */

if (!is_array($array)) {
  /* Used ireplace so that searches can be case insensitive */
  return str_ireplace($find, $replace, $array);
}

$newArray = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $newArray[$key] = md_str_replace($find, $replace, $value);
}

return $newArray;
}
```